# Change input id to incorrectly update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am concerned about this generic `onChange` handler for multiple input fields in React (although, this applies to vanilla JavaScript, as well):

```
const handleChange = e => {
  setSomeState({
    ...someState,
    [e.target.id]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

From the Elements tab in Chrome Dev Tools, I changed the `id` of one of the input fields to see if the state is updated with the key as the new `id` of the input or with the same that was assigned initially.

However, nothing bad happened and the state was updated with the originally assigned `id` of the input field, but is it possible, by any means, that the `id` of an input field is changed by a user that leads to the state being updated with an incorrect key?

For e.g., for an `input` field:

```
<input id="email" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
```

a user, on the frontend, changes the `id` to `username` (by any means, if possible) which in turns causes the generic `handleChange()` function to add additional data to the state with the key `username`, which originally is not defined or required.

If this is possible, I think it is best not to use generic change handlers and assign properties explicitly. But if this isn't, I would like to know, why?

Comment: Why do you think it's not best to use generic change handlers? The dictionary-like object setting is a common case. The only trouble would be probably typing it precisely (because as you said you never know exactly what's inside), but since you are apparently using pure js - ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: I am not saying that it's not best to use generic change handlers, I am just worried if the scenario I thought of (explained in the question) is possible?

Comment: Actually you asked a question and few words later you answered it by yourself _"However, nothing bad happened"_. If nothing bad happens, then it's fine I guess?

Comment: Yes, nothing bad happened the way I tried to manipulate the `id`, but don't know if there could be other means to do the same.

Comment: I think In React, the event object is a SyntheticEvent and its target is not the actual dom element but React's internal representation of it. That's why changing the dom directly doesn't change the id used by setState - beause React is using the data it has from its last render. I could be totally off here, btw.